# How to create a simulator and simulate real-time strategy game like Age of Empires Rise of Rome?

Tags: simulation

I would be interested to simulate an Age of Empires Rise of Rome gathering process of food, wood etc. Such simulator would help to acheive the economy growth and would find the optimized order to build buildings and gather recources. Note that the simulator would examine only economy process, not fighting. Is there any free software that would be easy to use and make such simulation? The question is how to simulate the process with simulator (not how to create real-time game).

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: Since what you describe are only about 20 lines of code, a framework would be excesive.  There are open source RTS engines, but exist to support the writting of the graphics and pathfinding.. things that you dont seems to need.  You are better looking in how you write a RTS strategy.

Comment: @Tei Could you please give an example of the '20 lines of code' solution that you propose?

Comment: Given that you minus the fighting, what you have got here is a description of a variant of the board game "Agricola"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peladao asked for a example of a RTS engine. I am writting a example code here, and commenting it.

pseudocode:

```
    loop:        
    "decide what want to build";
    "try to build that"; (a verification is made if resources are enough)
    "generate resources";
    goto loop;
```

Real code (javascript)

1) not interesting. defining functions to use later.

```
var rand = function(){
    return Math.random()*100;
};

var random = (function(){   
    return {
        betwen:function(min,max){
            return Math.random()*(max-min)+min;
        },
        element:function(datarray){ 
            var len = datarray.length;
            if(!len) return;
            var r = parseInt(this.betwen(0,len),10);
            return datarray[r];
        }   
    };
})();

var scroll = (function(){        
    var index = 0;
    var maximo = 10;

    return {
    cortarViejas:function(){
        var edadCorte = index - maximo;

        $(".logline").each(function(){
            if($(this).data("nace")<edadCorte)
                $(this).remove();           
        }); 
    },
    add:function(txt){
        var line = $("<div>");      
        line.addClass("logline");
        line.data("nace",index++);
        line.html(txt);

        $(line).insertAfter('#marca');

        this.cortarViejas();
    },
    error:function(txt){
        this.add("ERROR: "+txt);
    },
    battle:function(txt){
        this.add("Battle: "+ txt);
    },
    oceaniaDice:function(txt){
        this.add("[Oceania broadcast] "+ txt);
    },
    debugOceania:function(txt){
        this.add("[Oceania debug] "+ txt);
    }
    };

})();
```

2) heres the interesting part. Oceania is a empire that generate resources, and invest these resources in tanks or soldiers

```
var oceania = (function(){        

    var tanks = 0;
    var soldiers = 0;
    var build = "";//build strategy 
    var dead = 0;

    var prices = {"tank":5,"soldier":1};

    var hateLines = [ "Eastasia will be destroyed","We hate Eurasia","Our troops are doing good",
        "We have always ben at war with Eastasia","Under the spreading chestnut tree.I sold you and you sold me"];

    var metal = 0;
    var powerplants = 1;
    var factory = 3;    

    return {
    info:function(){
        scroll.debugOceania("Build strategy:"+ build);      
        scroll.debugOceania("Metal:"+ metal);       
        scroll.debugOceania("Army: soldier "+soldiers + ", tanks "+tanks );     
        scroll.debugOceania("Dead:"+ dead);     
    },
    militarTick:function(stuff){

        if(tanks>10 && soldiers > 20){
            tanks -= 10;
            soldiers -= 20;
            scroll.battle("Some units losts! 10 tanks, 20 soldiers");       
            dead += 10+ 20;
        }           
    },
```

3) Here, the empire execute his desire to build [stuff]

```
    buy:function(stuff){    
        if(!prices[stuff]) {
            scroll.error("buying what?:"+stuff);
            return;
        }
        if(prices[stuff]>metal) {
            scroll.debugOceania(stuff + " is too expensive");
            return;
        }
        metal -= prices[stuff];                 

        switch(stuff){
            case "tank":                            
                tanks++;    
                //scroll.debugOceania("Oceania create tank");               
                break;
            case "soldier":         
                soldiers++; 
                //scroll.debugOceania("Oceania create soldier");                
                break;      
        }       
    },
    buildTick:function(){
        switch(build){
            case "tanks":
                this.buy("tank");
                break;
            case "soldiers":
                this.buy("soldier");
                break;
        }
    },
```

3) Here, the empire decide what is his desire, based on tanks/soldiers ratio, ammount of soldiers, ammount of tanks, or any other strategy-level issue.

```
    strategyTick:function(){        
        var likeSoldiers=0,likeTanks=0;

        build = "nothing";

        //You have something, build something!
        if( metal> 10) //we have metal, lets buy soldiers!
            likeSoldier = 10;   

        //minimum this  
        if ( tanks < 10)
            likeTanks += 10;
        if ( soldiers< 20)
            likeSoldiers += 10;

        //we want 5 soldiers for 1 tank
        if ( soldiers < tanks * 5)
            likeSoldiers += 10;

        //if we have at least 40 soldiers, we would love to have more tanks!
        if ( soldiers > 40) 
            likeTanks += 10;

        //if we have at least 40 tanks, we would love to have moresoldiers!
        if ( tanks > 40) 
            likeSoldiers += 10;

        //we want soldiers more than anything else, lets build soldiers!
        if(likeSoldiers > likeTanks ){      
            build = "soldiers";
        }else 
        //we want tanks more than anything else, lets build soldiers!
        if(  likeTanks > 5) {
            build = "tanks";
        }               
    },
```

4) Everything after this line can be ignored.

```
    produccionTick:function(){
        var t;
        var energy = powerplants * 3;
        var factorycount = factory;
        var metalInitial = metal;

        for(t=0;t<energy,factorycount>0;t++,factorycount--){            
            metal = metal + 1;      
        }           
        //var produce = metal - metalInitial;
        //scroll.debugOceania("Oceania create "+ produce + " metal. Total now:"+metal);         
    },
    propagandaTick:function(){
        if(rand()<5) {
            var hate = random.element(hateLines);
            scroll.oceaniaDice(hate);
        }   
    },
    tick:function(){
        this.propagandaTick();
        this.produccionTick();
        this.strategyTick();
        this.buildTick();
        this.militarTick();
    }   
    };

})();



$(function(){
    $("#cmd").keyup(function(event){                    
        if (event.which == 13) {
            var command = $(this).val();

            $(this).val("");
            scroll.add(command);

            $("#cmd").focus();

            event.preventDefault();
        }  
    });


    $("#reload").click(function(){  
        document.location = "game.htm?r="+Math.random();
    });

    oceania.tick();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            oceania.tick();
        },300);
    });     
});
```

Comment: Which proves that "20 lines of code" was optimistic :-)  However, that's a really good example of a simple, functional game engine.

Comment: Oh I don't know, turn a pile of ';\r\n' into ';' and you could drop it pretty far :)